# node.js 9 and npm 5.5.1 : cannot run install correctly anymore

Tags: node.js, npm

After upgrading  my project to node.js 9.1.0 ( and bundle nom 5.5.1) I canot run install wo error . Even if the log output is 'verbose' , I do not understand WHERE is the issue ... help welcome

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
    2 info using npm@5.5.1
    3 info using node@v9.1.0
    4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
    5 info lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~prebuild: shopping-list@1.0.0
    6 info lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: shopping-list@1.0.0
    7 verbose lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    8 verbose lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Volumes/aragorn/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS/LearningVuejs2_Code/chapter7/ShoppingList/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Volumes/aragorn/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS/LearningVuejs2_Code/chapter7/ShoppingList/node_modules/.bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/Ghostscript/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/Users/yves/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/yves/.rvm/bin:/Users/yves/go/bin
    9 verbose lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Volumes/aragorn/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS/LearningVuejs2_Code/chapter7/ShoppingList
    10 silly lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'node build/build.js' ]
    11 silly lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle shopping-list@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
    13 verbose stack Error: shopping-list@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:135:13)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:224:7)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
    13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:135:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:224:7)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
    14 verbose pkgid shopping-list@1.0.0
    15 verbose cwd /Volumes/aragorn/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS/LearningVuejs2_Code/chapter7/ShoppingList
    16 verbose Darwin 17.2.0
    17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
    18 verbose node v9.1.0
    19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error shopping-list@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the shopping-list@1.0.0 build script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Im thinking about two posibilities. 1) Problem with code in build files. 2) Some module doesn't support new node version and fails to start. Vue Js book were written before node 9.1 come up. Which module i have no idea.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, it's not su funny that the log file cannot give any clue ?....

Comment: It gives you a clue. error code ELIFECYCLE means that code unexpectedly stops. or in other words crashed. Why? Good question. But in order to answer this we need to debug all modules and code included in that build script. From what i see i would check shelljs, webpack, ora..Check versions in package json and make sure that they support node version 9...Or just update those to most recent one.

Comment: I hope this is the script you trying to run https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Vuejs-2/blob/master/chapter7/shopping-list/build/build.js

Comment: not far .. it was my starting point , I am doing some extensions , it works until I upgraded to node 9 as Heroku deployment failed because of not using Node 9....

Comment: I installed and run yarn install ... wo any problem...

Comment: Problem may be not in install but in code itself in some module. For example in version 9 node may deprecate some stuff or change api, method calls or whatever and module doesn't fix it. And there you go. Bug and critical error.

Comment: I am looking back in my packages... will keep informed when solved... thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that everyone is effected by this. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19019

Answer (score 0):

I went back to node 8.9.1 / nvm 5.5.1 ( bundled) ... solved 
maybe too soon to upgrade to node 9....